# Delete rows in scipy matrix from list

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I have a list of integers called `cluster0Rand` corresponding to certain index's in a scipy sparse matrix called `data`.

I want to create a new scipy matrix consisting of only the row's which's index is in the list?

For example,

```
data = csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
cluster0Rand = [0,1]
```

The desired output would be:

```
csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3]])
```

How can I do this efficently given that the real list is made up of thousands of indexs and the scipy matrix is `(10000, 100000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, plain indexing does the job:

```
In [300]: data = sparse.csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
In [301]: idx = [0,1]
In [302]: data[idx,:]
Out[302]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [303]: _.A
Out[303]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

This kind of indexing is slower with sparse matrices than dense arrays.  But it uses a sparse matrix strength, matrix multiplication.  It turns the `idx` into a selector matrix.

```
In [313]: (sparse.csr_matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0]])*data).A
Out[313]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3]], dtype=int32)
```